# DismissViewController inside a NSObject Class

Tags: objective-c, nsobject, dismiss, multipeer-connectivity

I create a NSOBject class to work with MultipeerConnectivity, and for this I'm using this code below:

**DeviceConnect.m**

```
-(id)initConnectionWithDisplayName:(NSString*)value{

    myPeerID = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:value];

    mySession = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:self.myPeerID];

    mySession.delegate = self;

    browserVC = [[MCBrowserViewController alloc] initWithServiceType:@"chat" session:self.mySession];

    browserVC.delegate = self;

    browserVC.minimumNumberOfPeers = 1;
    browserVC.maximumNumberOfPeers = 1;

    advertiser = [[MCAdvertiserAssistant alloc] initWithServiceType:@"chat" discoveryInfo:nil session:mySession];

    [advertiser start];

    return self;
}

-(MCBrowserViewController*)pushConnectView{
    return browserVC;
}

- (void)browserViewControllerWasCancelled:(MCBrowserViewController *)browserViewController{
    NSLog(@"dismiss the screen");
    [browserVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**MyViewController.m**

```
DeviceConnect *devices = [[DeviceConnect alloc] initConnectionWithDisplayName:[UIDevice currentDevice].name];    
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:[devices pushConnectView] animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This code works perfectly except the delegate method **browserViewControllerWasCancelled** recognizing when we click the button **cancel** existing within the browserVC class, why this method is not being called?

Now, if I throw up these codes within the class myViewController.m this method back to work, but it makes the code very messy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you really called function DeviceConnect::browserViewControllerWasCancelled?

You should attach Button Cancel touch-up-inside event to some function, then call dismiss vc function.

Maybe following code will help you.

MyViewController.m (Suppose that you have attach cancel button to this function)

```
-(IBAction)clickCancel:(id)sender
{
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is the delegate for MCBrowserViewController is being released. You are only creating a local variable then displaying the MCBrowserViewController attached to it. The local variable gets released because no one has a strong reference to it even though you are displaying the MCBrowserViewController.

Instead of

```
DeviceConnect *devices = [[DeviceConnect alloc] initConnectionWithDisplayName:[UIDevice currentDevice].name];
```

Make devices a property or an instance variable. Then it shouldn't be released and the MCBrowserViewController delegate will work properly.

I hope that fixes your issue.